# Laravel load external URL in modal window

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-livewire

I have a button on my blade which opens a modal window in laravel-livewire like

```
<a href="#" wire:click="confirmI">
```

Also, here's my controller

```
public function confirmI() 
    {
        $this->reset();
        $this->eurl='https://websiteurl.com';
        $this->confirmingI = true;
    }
```

and my model in blade

```
<x-jet-dialog-modal wire:model="confirmingI">
 <x-slot name="title">
            WebPage
        </x-slot>
 <x-slot name="content">
            <div class="flex -mx-3 mt-2">
here is data
</div>
</x-slot>
 <x-slot name="footer">
 </x-slot>
</x-jet-dialog-modal>
```

What I want is load `$eurl` value website contents in modal where is reads

> "here is data"

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of [file_get_contents](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_file_get_contents.asp) *— Reads entire file into a string*

```
$this->eurl = file_get_contents('https://google.com');
```

[Displaying Unescaped Data](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#displaying-unescaped-data)

```
<div class="flex -mx-3 mt-2">
    {!! $eurl !!}
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<x-jet-dialog-modal>
 <x-slot name="title">
            WebPage
        </x-slot>
 <x-slot name="content">
    <div class="flex -mx-3 mt-2">
        {{ $confirmingI }}
    </div>
</x-slot>
 <x-slot name="footer">
 </x-slot>
</x-jet-dialog-modal>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks what is $confirmingI value, I actually want to load external website in content and though URL